# Is this a proper proof for Transitivity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

This may not be correct, but this is what I have for an attempt to prove transitivity in this particular instance:

> Prove that $Rn = \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}: n \mid x − y\}$ is transitive.

$$\frac{x – y}{n} = k \quad \text{(for some integer $k$)} \\
\frac{y – z}{n} = w \quad \text{(for some integer w)} \\
\frac{x – z}{n} = kw$$

If $k$ and $w$ are both integers, then the product of $k$ and $w$ is also an integer. Therefore, $Rn$ is transitive. Is this proof correct?

Comment: `(x – z) / n = kw` Where did that come from?

Comment: That's a good question, thats the only part I'm questioning.  I guess I need to show how to get to that step.

Comment: Try this, instead: $$\frac{x-z}{n} = \frac{(x-y)+(y-z)}{n} = k+w \;\;\in\;\;\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Ah, so its the sum of k and w.  I plugged some numbers into my first attempt to check my proof and it just happened that after plugging in some numbers, my k and w turned out such that their product was the same as their sum (the numbers n and k were 2 and 2 respectively).  Thank you